# Not able to run simple app using Titanium

Tags: ios4, titanium, appcelerator, linker-errors, appcelerator-mobile

I'm new to Titanium Framework. I've created a new project, and without making any modifications to ma code, I get errors when I try to Compile/Run for iPhone.

Here is the complete log that I get in console:

```
[INFO] One moment, building ...
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 1.8.0.1 (12/22/11 13:09 fbdc96f)
[INFO] iPhone Device family: universal
[INFO] iPhone SDK version: 5.0
[INFO] iPhone simulated device: ipad
[INFO] Performing full rebuild. This will take a little bit. Hold tight...
[INFO] Skipping JS compile, running from simulator
[ERROR] /Users/bhaveshjain/Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/TitaAppDemo/build/iphone/Classes/GDataXMLNode.h:39:9: fatal error: 'libxml/tree.h' file not found [2]
[ERROR] /Users/bhaveshjain/Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/TitaAppDemo/build/iphone/Classes/GDataXMLNode.h:39:9: fatal error: 'libxml/tree.h' file not found [2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Also, one important thing, I have two Xcode installed in my Mac.

Xcode: 3.2.4 with iOS 4.2
Xcode: 4.2 with iOS5

Comment: have you build for device before, and now tried to add a new module? If so, please remove the build files, and re-compile. That should do the trick

Comment: @Topener Nopes ... I am trying it from Scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem as i was having Xcode 4.0 and 4.2 installed..

With two Xcode installed in my mac i was not able to run the application from my titanium studio.

So to run the app goto your titanium workspace and under your project >>build>>iphone.
you will find the xcode project of your titanium app. run that project with your xcode 3.2.4.

if you have updated your titanium sdk to the latest one i.e 1.7.x then you can run it with ios sdk 5 too..

As for now i have removed my older xcode and by doing it everything works fine.

Comment: Nopes that is not working , Even though I removed the Xcode4 with iOS5, titanium is not able to get the path for iOS 4.2 of XCode3.2.Even we can;t set that path manually. Now in in trap :(

Comment: The answer is satisfactory, but for me ,it worked when I uninstalled the Xcode 3.2 & reinstalled Xcode4.2 with iOS5. :)